# C# update database table form a programatically created form

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a form created **programatically** which contains a **TextBox** bound to a **DataTable**. I'm using the [Chinook](https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/) database. Some of the behavior is ok (reading the database), but I'm not able to save the changes on the database. I don't know what's wrong.

The SQL code is (I'm using SQL Server 2014):

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Artist]
(
    [ArtistId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(120),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Artist] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ArtistId])
);
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Artist] ([ArtistId], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'AC/DC');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Artist] ([ArtistId], [Name]) VALUES (2, N'Accept');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Artist] ([ArtistId], [Name]) VALUES (3, N'Aerosmith');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Artist] ([ArtistId], [Name]) VALUES (4, N'Alanis Morissette');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Artist] ([ArtistId], [Name]) VALUES (5, N'Alice In Chains');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Artist] ([ArtistId], [Name]) VALUES (6, N'Antônio Carlos Jobim');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Artist] ([ArtistId], [Name]) VALUES (7, N'Apocalyptica');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Artist] ([ArtistId], [Name]) VALUES (8, N'Audioslave');
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Artist] ([ArtistId], [Name]) VALUES (9, N'BackBeat');
...
```

The code is (just a new project with a button in it):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    protected Form FForm;
    private SqlCommand FSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
    protected BindingSource FBindingSource = new BindingSource();
    protected SqlDataAdapter FSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    protected DataSet FDataSet = new DataSet();
    protected DataTable FDataTable = new DataTable();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=***; Initial Catalog=Chinook; User ID=sa; Password=***";
        con.Open();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FForm = new Form();
        FForm.Visible = true;

        FSqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Artist", con);
        FSqlDataAdapter.Fill(FDataTable);
        FBindingSource.DataSource = FDataTable;

        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.DataBindings.Add("Text", FBindingSource, "name", true);
        tb.Left = 16;
        tb.Top = 16;
        tb.Width = 100;
        FForm.Controls.Add(tb);

        Button btnSave = new Button();
        btnSave.Text = "Save";
        btnSave.Left = 16;
        btnSave.Top = 48;
        btnSave.Width = 75;
        FForm.Controls.Add(btnSave);
        btnSave.Click += btnSave_Click;
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(FSqlDataAdapter);
        FSqlDataAdapter.Update(FDataTable);
        FForm.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any exceptions or tables are just empty/not updated?

Comment: @cassandrad: Tables are populated with the original data. The first artist is AC/DC

Answer (score 0):

Try this (EDITED) instead:

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=***; Initial Catalog=Chinook; User ID=sa; Password=***"))
        using (new SqlCommandBuilder(FDataTable))
        {
            adapter.Fill(table);
            con.Open();
            adapter.Update(table);
        }
    }
```

I din't see the connection establishing in your button. Also: Don't let your connection open. Always use `using()` so your connection will be closed if not needed. As example: Your software gets big and complicated with many sql statements and suddenly, it crashes. There is still a connection open to your SQL Server. With `using()` it will be closed as soon as it ends.

Also: it saves some space, but that is important when you write big software.

Comment: It doesn't work. Still doesn't commit any changes to the database. The connection was opened with the constructor, but thank you for the advice

Comment: @jciberta Hm. Okay actually my code is wrong. Do you commit the changes into the adapter? Like, in my code I just get everything from the Database and Update it. That wont make any changes. Can you show us how you get the Updated entry into you table? Lets assume you got a GridView. Do you get all the entries and put it into you Adapter?

Comment: This is the whole code. A form with a TextBox bound to a table. I assume SqlCommandBuilder builds the UPDATE command, so FSqlDataAdapter.Update(FDataTable) should update the table. Am I wrong?

Comment: Usually, yes. Maybe take a look where I learnt it. https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommandbuilder

Answer (score 0):

I've found what's missing. Before update changes, you need to "Applies pending changes to the underlying data source" with the [EndEdit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.EndEdit);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method.

So, it works with:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FBindingSource.EndEdit();
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(FSqlDataAdapter);
        FSqlDataAdapter.Update(FDataTable);
        FForm.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Because inside your btnSave_Click is the var FSqlDataAdapter where
there query inside of it is "Select * from Artist".

You must use update query to be able to update your data into  database

Comment: `SqlCommandBuilder` should create the `UpdateCommand` if the `SelectCommand`is set

Comment: oh. now I know.